# how to call a form based authentication from curl or wget

Tags: curl, wget

I want to call an url using `curl` and `wget`.

I tried:

```
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'user=foo&password=bar' http://server.com/Login

wget --load-cookies cookies.txt -p http://server.com/interesting/article.jsp
```

But the login form is not accepting post data; any other way I can do this?

Comment: How do you know that the parameters are `user` and `password`? Look at the source for the login form and include the `<form ...>` and everything up to the `</form>` in your question. Or just make sure to emulate those parameters.

Comment: @Mowgli As this question stands, it's basically unanswerable (it doesn't include the relevant parts of the original form). The original asker never updated it, either. I suggest you edit it to include the HTML form stuff (and maybe other improvements, like the tags), and maybe also offer a bounty on the question...

Comment: I know, I am trying to get a source code of a page but I have to login to page in order to get access to sites content and login is simple form based login.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find partial solution using load cookies with wget. 
Here is Google Chrome extension to export cookies [Chrome Google Export Extension](http://goo.gl/L45gn)
use this cookie with wget

1. Install Google Chrome Extension.
2. Login to site via Google Chrome
3. Export Cookie using Chrome extension
4. Somewhere may be same place where wget or desktop.
5. now run following wget command with full path to cookies.txt

Example

```
wget -x --load-cookies C:\Users\Documents\GnuWin32\bin\cookies.txt http://example.com/some_interesting/article/1.html
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

For the record: Mowgli's solution did not work for me (no Chrome in my environment), so after some digging I found the issue:

form-based authentication usually sets session cookies, but `wget` does not save them by default.

So using a command like:

`wget --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies /tmp/cookiefile --post-data='username=User&password=Pwd123' <login URL>`

or somewhat safer:

`wget --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies /tmp/cookiefile --post-file creds <login URL>`

where the file `creds` would contain the same pair `username=User&password=Pwd123` (no end-of-line!) does the job.

Then `--load-cookies /tmp/cookiefile` should be accepted by the site.

Comment: Tried this w/my modem: `wget --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies /tmp/cookiefile --post-data='username=admin&password=itspw' http://192.168.100.1/RouterStatus.htm` but got this: `Connecting to 192.168.100.1:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.`